# parse byte count in ftp log

Tags: bash, ftp

I'm running on an arm architecture.
Should be a bash script.
I would like to graph total bytes coming and out of my ftp server.

I parse the ftp.log file with this command to get this output:

```
    `cat ftp.log | grep loaded`
```

the interesting lines are in this format:

`Sep 14 18:46:00 sharecenter pure-ftpd: (doc@omega) [NOTICE] /mnt/HD/HD_a2//SAVE/backupffp.sh downloaded  (423 bytes, 0.78KB/sec)
Sep 15 22:06:47 sharecenter pure-ftpd: (doc@omega) [NOTICE] /mnt/HD/HD_a2//SAVE/ffp-2013-09-14.tar.bz2 downloaded  (904753213 bytes, 1928.17KB/sec)
Sep 15 22:32:26 sharecenter pure-ftpd: (doc@omega) [NOTICE] /mnt/HD/HD_a2//SAVE/test.avi uploaded  (576711530 bytes, 1465.80KB/sec)`

Now I need to get the values after the "(" and before the word "bytes" and add them.

- Example:

--> downloaded 423+904753213=904753636 => returned value: 904753636

--> uploaded 576711530 => returned value: 576711530

Now the script will run every 5 minutes, so the result has to take into account only the numbers between the last 5 minutes.
Example:
At 22:05 script runs and adds all bytes. When script runs again at 22:10 only the transfered bytes between 22:05 to 22:10 should be added.

For rrd you need a simple output, 2 variables "dowloaded" and "uploaded".
So I will need those 2 values in those 2 variables.

I hope I am clear enough, if not don't hesitate to ask for more information.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This version would be strict with the format. It would work even if some parts would have added spaces like in the file URLs.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    u = d = 0
}

match($0, / downloaded  \([0-9]+/) {
    d += substr($0, RSTART + 14, RLENGTH - 14)
    next
}

match($0, / uploaded  \([0-9]+/) {
    u += substr($0, RSTART + 12, RLENGTH - 12)
}

END {
    printf("downloaded=%d\nuploaded=%d\n", d, u)  ## You can change this to have desired format of output.
}
```

Output:

```
> awk -f script.awk file
downloaded=904753636
uploaded=576711530
```

Condensed format:

```
awk 'BEGIN{u=d=0}match($0,/ downloaded  \([0-9]+/){d+=substr($0,RSTART+14,RLENGTH-14);next}match($0,/ uploaded  \([0-9]+/){u+=substr($0,RSTART+12,RLENGTH-12)}END{printf("downloaded=%d\nuploaded=%d\n",d,u)}' file
```

To run it on a bash script, run awk as input through process substitution, change the format to `"%d\n%d\n"` and read two lines with two variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ read downloaded; read uploaded; } < <(exec awk 'BEGIN{u=d=0}match($0,/ downloaded  \([0-9]+/){d+=substr($0,RSTART+14,RLENGTH-14);next}match($0,/ uploaded  \([0-9]+/){u+=substr($0,RSTART+12,RLENGTH-12)}END{printf("%d\n%d\n",d,u)}' file)
echo "Downloaded: $downloaded"
echo "Uploaded: $uploaded"
```

Comment: Wow that's impressive, I wish I knew how to manipulate all those powerful tools.

Comment: The bash script doesn't work for me. I do not know how I post the errors I am getting. Should I use the comment or answer.

Comment: @user2782004 You can just comment it here.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. This one is fun:

```
for i in $(grep -P -o '(?<=downloaded \()[0-9]+(?= bytes)' file.txt); do ((downloaded+=i)); done
echo "Downloaded: $downloaded"
```

> Now the script will run every 5 minutes, so the result has to take into account only the numbers between the last 5 minutes.

And there are many ways to do this as well. One of them is using `tail -f` instead of running it every 5 minutes. Another one is to remember file line count(for example with `wc -l`) and then you can use tail to get appended part only.

Comment: "And there are many ways to do this as well." Which ways please?

Comment: @user2782004 I gave you the clues. ``wc -l`` should tell you the number of lines (for example 35). Now, after 5 minutes if you do it again, you'll get a bigger number (for example 40). This way you know that you should only parse last 5 lines, so you use ``tail -n 5`` or ``tail -n +35`` to get the newest part.